# Generate and execute JavaFX jar using maven

Tags: maven, javafx, jar

I'm trying to generate and execute a simple runnable jar using the following JavaFX - Maven template (eclipse : Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) Build id: 2018)

[image]

It comes with a simple JavaFX GUI, i compiled the program just fine (i'm using JDK 10, jre 10.0.2) on Eclipse IDE, however i don't know how to generate an executable jar file and run it, if i do it using Eclipse export->Runnable jar i get the famous "java.lag.NullPointerException : Location is required" Eror message on line 14 of the main.java file.

I saerched for this error and couldn't fix it, since i'm using only one fxml file and it's already in the resources/fxml directory i don't know why it's still getting a null value from the getResource() method...

Here's the project structure and Main class code 
:[image]

The problem is that this line of code :

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
```

public class MainApp extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

    stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Is it eclipse's way of generating the jar that's wrong, or is that a better way of generating the runnable jar for maven projects ?

Comment: Have you tried using the simpler Export: Jar File instead of Runnable Jar File? I have never been able to get the runnable version to work and have always used the simpler. And, this export does include a Manifest, so I don't understand the documentation that says the distinction is that only the Runnable version has a Manifest. I'm not familiar with Maven so this comment may not be helpful at all.

Comment: I tried generating a simple jar, but when i click on it nothing happens, when i try to run with "java -jar myjar.jar" command it tells me that there's no manifest file. so i can't execute the jar file. EDIT: I also tried to generate a simple java project through eclipse javaFX project (without using maven, nor fxml file), and double clicking on the generated jar still gives me the same error, but running it via the command line works just fine, so the problem is locating the fxml files when running the jar...

Answer (score 0):

I think that your string argument in `getResources()` will result in searching for the following:

```
AddressAppNew/fxml/Scene.fxml
```

Since the file is in the "src/main/resources" package, you will have to include those packages and subpackages as part of the address.

I'd try the following:

```
getClass().getResource("/src/main/resources/fxml/Scene.fxml")
```

or maybe this:

```
getClass().getResource("../../../../resources/fxml/Scene.fxml")
```

The latter is based on `MainApp` being located in the folder

```
AddressAppNew/src/main/java/com/corp/AdressAddNew
```

I can't find the API of the syntax for the interpretation of the getResource() string argument. I *think* that "/" at the start refers to the project root, and without the "/" the string is added to the folder location of the invoked class. But I could be wrong. It's fussy and often I have to resort to some fumbling around to get the correct address string.

Comment: sadly both of your suggestions didn't work and i'm stillgeting the same error. As far as i know, putthing the first "/" in the getResource() is for the absolute path an the research begins from the "src/main/resources" folder, that's why "/fxml/Scene.fxml". I also tried with a relative path "Scene.fxml" without the "/" and it works if i put the "Scene.fxml" file in the same folder as MainApp.java. i don't know why, but neither the absolute path  nor the relative one works when running the jar while it's working just fine on my IDE...

Comment: I've *never* read about an absolute path starting at a folder named *resources*. Maybe that is a Maven thing? It's not part of Java API, afaik. Suggestion: if getResources("Scene.fxml") works, then do multiple iterations, e.g., getResources("../Scene.fxml") where Scene.fxml has been put in "corp" package, or ("fxml/Scene.fxml") where fxml subfolder is in AppAdressNew and work your way to the desired file structure.